# Are Agents of Shield Storylines/character ever referenced in MCU films?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, reference, agents-of-shield

Are any of the storylines or characters from Marvel's Agents of Shield ever referenced in the MCU movies?

Answer (score 7):

Quotes from Chloe Bennet, basically confirming there are no references in the movies at all

> I don’t know. People who make movies for Marvel, why don’t you acknowledge what happens on our show? Why don’t you guys go ask them that? Cause they don’t seem to care!
>
> The Marvel Cinematic Universe loves to pretend that everything is connected, but then they don’t acknowledge our show at all. So, I would love to do that, but they don’t seem to keen on that idea.

Source: http://www.slashfilm.com/agents-of-shield-marvel-movies-crossover/

Apart from Phil Coulson and Nick Fury, none of the characters from the TV show are referenced in the MCU movies.

The other way around, there are a lot of (small) references/easter eggs from the movies tying in on AoS. Some I can think of atm:

**Age of ultron**: http://ew.com/article/2015/05/05/agents-shield-age-ultron-crossover/
**Sokovia Accords**: http://www.cinemablend.com/television/How-Captain-America-Civil-War-Tied-With-Agents-H-I-E-L-137187.html
**Dr. Strange**: http://comicbook.com/marvel/2017/05/16/agents-of-shield-doctor-strange-ghost-rider/

I've watched all MCU movies and all Agents of Shield seasons

Comment: Can you elaborate more and add a few references?

Comment: Elaborated with a quote from the lead actress. Do you mean references, as in references to the movies in the tv shows or links to other websites?

Comment: Both if possible.

Comment: Soooo your answer is "NO"...right? Seems to me that the rest is irrelevant,

Comment: Dang, if I just posted an answer saying `NO` it would've spared me a downvote...

Answer (score -1):

Basically Agents of SHIELD is introduced as sweeper cover for Marvel Cinematic Universe's consequences so main flow is from movie to series, means there are lots of references of movie in the series and also including some characters but there are minor references of series in movies.

For Avengers movie, There isn't any major story from TV , but the Helicarrier in Age of Ultron is from TV story. That Helicarrier is not explained anywhere in movies just Fury stating 'Brought from an Old Friend(Phil Coulson)', that friend isn't available in movie storyline(as he dead in movies).

Comment: This is true but doesn't actually answer the question. If there are references to the series in the movies...name them.

Comment: Helicarrier was the reference from tv-series to movies, As SHIELD was dissambled after CA:WS, Nick Fury did not have any Helicarrier, and Phil Coulson was secretly repairing a helicarrier under theta protocol for emergency uses, which is used by Fury in Age of Ultron. So for movies' storyline that Helicarrier is from outside of storyline, It is borrowed from TV so technically it's a reference.

Comment: No...the helicarrier appeared first in the movie...it was explained **after** in the TV series that it was the "secret" thing Coulson was working on.

Comment: Sort of. Coulson had been bouncing around the world all season for some secret mission with no explanation. After AoU, he explains that it had been an effort to get the helicarrier.

Comment: Yes, This is an easter egg not direct story reference, You were asking for direct impacting storyline from tv, that is not available in movies, but there are chances if they show Quicksliver who is not dead, So there can be T.A.H.I.T.I somewhere in movies.

Comment: Also, IIRC, that helicarrier project is repeatedly referenced in the show as "Theta Protocol", in the episodes leading up to the film. In *Age of Ultron*, Fury says he got the helicarrier from "an old friend"; to viewers of the TV show, it's clearly Coulson that he's referring to (because why even bring it up otherwise?).

Answer (score -4):

Yes, the very main character of MAOS Agent Phil Colson was in the first Avenger's movie i.e. Marvel's The Avengers.

Comment: Phil Colson was first in film, I think OP asking fro reverse of it